Diff bug if only white-space was removed
The "revisions" section's difference highlighting marks too mutch as changed whenever only white-space was removed, for example:

Also, sometimes the wrong lines are considered as added, again if white-space was removed:

Note that if not fixed yet, then above can be reproduced using the link:
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24910671/revisions

first example is definitely something worth addressing. while the second screenshot is a little bewildering, I personally wouldn't go as far as to classify it as a bug. probably as an area for potential improvement.
